# Can I push page data into marketo manually

Tags: marketo

We have a site built where our customers come to buy some digital content. But most of the clients use the digital content for marketing campaigns. And employ marketo and many other automation products to track leads.

We have a custom built web analytics tool for our site,which is not robust enough. But our clients just want to know if any leads visited our website and push this event to marketo or any other marketing automation tool. I was wondering if there is a way to read the marketo cookie and send a very simple "site visited" data to marketo so that the client is aware that the prospective lead has read the digital content they brought from us? Does this require a marketo API Key?

We also want to achieve this without embedding any Marketo Munckin codes in our digital content.

Can this be generalized to include other marketing tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way this worked for me .

The idea here is to get a unique Marketo-id from client and use just Munchkin.init to register a 'page visited' for that client , who might have filled a landing page data earlier.
And then goahead and read the marketo cookie for that browser as mentioned in their blog here. 
http://developers.marketo.com/blog/get-a-visitors-cookie-id-and-then-query-associated-lead-data/

This data can also be pushed from backend server with hardcoded script for marketo. This way you can control what data you can send to Marketo and also correlate the user uniquely from Marketo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get analytic info on how many visitor reached specific target page, you can use Google Analytics in your site and define targets. It will not identify which lead visited. For that you must implement Munchkin Cookie of Marketo.

Comment: I only need to push the data from my backend system. I do not want to embed marketo javascript on every page on my site.

Comment: In this case you can use "Visited Web Page" filter in your Marketo smart campaign, it will capture if lead visited the site.

Comment: As i said. the marketo campaign is run by my clients. I do not have control over the filters. I need to be able to correlate the web analytics data with marketo leads.

Comment: I am afraid to say but there is no way you can ready marketo cookies info from third party system, either you need to  put tracking code in your site or capture page visited feature from marketo itself.

Comment: you are right. I cant read the cookie. But is it possible to push a data from my webserver without knowing the api/auth key to marketo datastore